# Is there any reasonable arithmetic way to represent $n$ XOR $2n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science

Subject mostly says it all. I'm curious whether there's a "nice" way to represent $n \oplus 2n$ for a given $n\in\mathbb N$.

I found a few other questions along these lines, but it seems like in general the best representations were somewhat involved usages of mod/floor/sums/recursion. Is that really the best that can be done for this question? It may well be, and I guess that would speak to a foundational incompatibility between familiar arithmetic and bitwise operations.

For reference, values of $n \oplus 2n$ for $n \leq 16$:

$${3, 6, 5, 12, 15, 10, 9, 24, 27, 30, 29, 20, 23, 18, 17, 48}\ .$$

Comment: The sequence is discussed at http://oeis.org/A048724 and if you don't find any "nice" representations there (or in the references linked there) then take that as pretty strong evidence that no "nice" representation exists.